# How to select random key with common values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random, key-value

so I'm trying to create an AI just for fun, but I've run into a problem. Currently when you say `Hi` it will say `Hi` back. If you say something it doesn't know, like `Hello`, it will ask you to define it, and then add it to a dictionary variable `knowledge`. Then whenever you say `Hello`, it translates it into `Hi` and will say `Hi`.

But, I want it to loop through what you've defined as `hi` and say a random thing that means `hi`. So if you tell it `Hello`, `What's Up`, and `Greetings` all mean hi, it will work to say any of them and it will return `Hi`. But how would I make it say either `Hi`, `Hello`, `What's Up`, or `Greetings` once it knows them? (just examples)

I have tried this:

```
def sayHello():
  for index, item in enumerate(knowledge):
    if knowledge[item] == 'HI':
      print(knowledge[index] + "! I'm Orion!")
```

However I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 28, in <module>
  File "python", line 12, in sayHello
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: The title is relatively on-topic but the context in your question is far too broad. If you already have an approach in mind and are stuck at the last hurdle, please just give us that specific issue

Comment: The problem is `enumerate(knowledge)` gives you tuples of `(0, key0)`, `(1, key1)` etc... which is entirely different from what your code expects.   Since your code is trying to access `knowledge[0]` and you don't have a `0` key, it's giving you the `KeyError`.  You might be looking for `knowledge.items()` which give you tuples of `(key, item)` instead.  Either way though, you haven't even implemented a `random` element into the function.  Why would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs thing you need is your initial dictionary with only `hi`. Then we say something to our friend.  We check all the values, if our phrase is not in there, we ask for the phrase to be defined.  We create a new key with that definition along with a default empty list.  We then append the phase to that list. Else, we search which value list our phrase lies in and select a random word from that list.

```
from random import choice

knowledge = {'hi': ['hi']}
while True:
    new = input('Say something to HAL: ')
    check = list(*knowledge.values())
    if new.lower() not in check:
        key = input('Define {} for me: '.format(new))
        knowledge.setdefault(key.lower(), [])
        knowledge[key].append(new.lower())
    else:
        for k, v in knowledge.items():
            if new.lower() in v:
                print(choice(v).title())
```

> ```
> Say something to HAL: hi 
> Hi
> Say something to HAL: hey
> Define hey for me: hi
> Say something to HAL: hey
> Hey
> Say something to HAL: hey
> Hi
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
knowledge = {"hi": ["hi"]}
```

And when your AI learns that  `new_word` means the same as `"hi"`:

```
knowledge["hi"].append(new_word)
```

So now, if you now say hi to your AI (this uses the random module):

```
print(random.choice(knowledge["hi"]))
```